# Make both sql queries work at the same time

Tags: php, sql, zip

I have two queries in one php file but only the second query gets executed. But the first query does not get executed. What could i be doing wrong? Here is my code.

```
<?php include('connections/pgconn.php'); ?>
<?php


function cleanData(&$str)
{
$str = preg_replace("/\t/", "\\t", $str);
$str = preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", $str);
if(strstr($str, '"')) $str = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str) . '"';
}

// filename for download
$filename = "eastafrica_revenue_monthly" . date('Ymd') . ".xls";

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");

$flag = false;
$result = pg_query("SELECT to_char (a.CALLDATE,'yyyymm') as month,min(a.calldate) as   start_time,max(a.calldate) as end_time,
   sum(a.alltaxcost::integer) AS revenue,
     COUNT (DISTINCT a.IDENTIFIANT) AS distinct_callers,
a.zoneiddest as country_code,b.country
FROM cdr_data a,COUNTRY_CODES b
WHERE  a.CALLSUBCLASS = '002'
     AND a.CALLCLASS = '008'
and a.zoneiddest::integer > 0
AND SUBSTR (a.CALLEDNUMBER, 1, 2) NOT IN
('77', '78', '75', '70', '71', '41', '31', '39', '76','79')
and  substr(a.zoneiddest,1,3)  in ('254','255','211','257','250')
and trim(a.zoneiddest)  = trim(b.country_code)
GROUP BY to_char (a.CALLDATE,'yyyymm') ,a.zoneiddest,b.country
ORDER BY 1");

while(false !== ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result))) {
if(!$flag) {
  // display field/column names as first row
  echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\r\n";
  $flag = true;
}
array_walk($row, 'cleanData');
echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\r\n";
}


?>

<?php
function cleanData2(&$str)
{
$str = preg_replace("/\t/", "\\t", $str);
$str = preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", $str);
if(strstr($str, '"')) $str = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str) . '"';
}

// filename for download
$filename = "international_revenue_daily" . date('Ymd') . ".xls";

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");

$flag = false;
$result = pg_query("SELECT to_char (a.CALLDATE,'yyyymmdd') as transdate,
    sum(a.alltaxcost::integer) AS revenue,
     COUNT (DISTINCT a.IDENTIFIANT) AS distinct_callers,
a.zoneiddest as country_code,b.country
FROM cdr_data a,  COUNTRY_CODES b
WHERE  a.CALLSUBCLASS = '002'
     AND a.CALLCLASS = '008'
and a.zoneiddest::integer > 0
AND SUBSTR (a.CALLEDNUMBER, 1, 2) NOT IN
('77', '78', '75', '70', '71', '41', '31', '39', '76','79')
and not substr(a.zoneiddest,1,3) in ('254','255','211','257','250','256')
and trim(a.zoneiddest)  = trim(b.country_code)
GROUP BY to_char (a.CALLDATE,'yyyymmdd') ,a.zoneiddest,b.country
ORDER BY 1") ;

while(false !== ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result))) {
if(!$flag) {
  // display field/column names as first row
  echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\r\n";
  $flag = true;
}
array_walk($row, 'cleanData2');
echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\r\n";
}
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Why are you sending your headers twice? Also, sending headers after echo should give you a warning.

Comment: Because these two queries where in two separate files and i am trying to combine them and have them executed in one file. What do i need to correct?

Comment: You want to offer a single file download of monthly and daily revenue? Remove the `header` calls in the second part of the script.

Comment: No i want to offer two files for download. Is it possible this way? i tried what your suggesting before i posted the question.

Comment: No. You cannot offer two downloads for a single request.

Comment: OK thanks. In that case if these queries where put in separate files it still wouldnt be possible to have two downloads with just one click of a button? There is no way round it?

Comment: You could archive (zip) the two files and offer that as a download. Or use javascript to open each file/url in a new window.

Comment: As a zip looks like a good idea. How can i go about it and where can i read from with an example?

Comment: Have a look at [ZipArchive](http://php.net/ZipArchive). You could use `addFromString` to create the files you are trying to `echo` in your example.